# About hyperplanes cutting the discrete hypercube

Tags: co.combinatorics, fourier-analysis, discrete-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-geometry

Given $\{-1,1\}^n$ we randomly choose a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now given an integer $p \in [1,n]$ and a number $\epsilon \in [0,1]$, I want to ask, "*How likely is it that at least one of the $p-$dimensional faces of the discrete hypercube gets sliced by this plane and has $< \epsilon$ fraction of points on either of the linear fragments so produced on that face?*"

- Is this question well defined?
- Do we know anything about this?

---

Somewhat related previous MO discussions, [faces in the discrete cube](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117912/faces-in-the-discrete-cube) and 
[Partitioning the vertices of an n-cube with random hyperplane cuts](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98516/partitioning-the-vertices-of-an-n-cube-with-random-hyperplane-cuts?rq=1) and [Directed Hypercube Minimal Cuts](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/195403/directed-hypercube-minimal-cuts?rq=1)

Comment: Do you mean a hyperplane through the origin?  Otherwise, there's no such thing as a random hyperplane.

Comment: By "hyperplane" I mean any affine space. Consider any function of the form, $\vec{a}.\vec{x}+b =0$.

Comment: In that case, there is no uniform random choice.   You would need to specify the distribution.  And if that distribution allows $b$ to be large compared to $|\vec{a}|$, it is very likely that the hyperplane will miss your hypercube entirely.

Comment: Maybe this is a way to think of what I am trying to convey : Fix the choice of $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$. Now can one show that there is an universal upper bound on the probabilities I am looking for? (...for example see what happens in say the Sperner's Theorem..there is an universal upperbound on the number of solutions of a linear equation on the discrete hypercube and that upperbound doesn't depend on the $\vec{a}$ or $b$ that one starts with..)

Comment: That still doesn't make sense to talk about "probability."  As for extremal bounds, some hyperplanes (e.g., $x_1 =1$) contain faces entirely, and some (e.g., $x_1 =0$) cut things in half very neatly.  What more specifically are you really trying to ask?  (Perhaps it would help us understand what you want if you describe your motivation.)

Comment: Lets say it this way : Is there any inequality version of the Sperner's theorem? Like saying "At most so many solutions can be found on the $\{-1,1\}^n$ of the inequation $\vec{a}.\vec{x} < b$". Then say I am  trying to count solutions to such inequations that live on the $p$ dimensional faces.